# GraphQLList and react

Tags: reactjs, graphql, relay

I am new to graphql and relay, but i do all the things alright.
I try to fetch my site properties list (`new GraphQLList(Property)`) using graphql query and there is no problem here, all properties fetched but the `props.properties` in my react component valued by:

```
{
    __dataID__: "client:11752076762",
    properties: {
        __dataID__: "client:11752076762",
        __status__: 4
    },
    __status__: 4
}
```

instead of fetched properties.

i confused, what's the problem? :(

Answer (score 1):

Try running the query in the graphiql first.

```
...
  .use('/graphql', graphqlHTTP({ schema, pretty: true, graphiql: true }))
```

Then try to confirm that you are getting what you are looking for in that query

Answer (score 0):

This could be related to how you:

- Define your GraphQL schema (please provide schema if possible)
- Declare the GraphQL data fragment requirements in your Relay.Container (you need to declare all the fields that you want explicitly)
- Declare the GraphQL route in your Relay.Route

Relay.Container example:

```
Relay.createContainer(App, {
  fragments: {
    properties:  () => Relay.QL`
      fragment on Properties {

        <IMPORTANT: fields that you want to be in props.properties should be here> 

      }
    `
    ...
  }
}
```

Relay.Route example:

```
Relay.Route {
  static queries = {
    properties: () => Relay.QL`
      query {
        properties
      }
    `,
  }
}
```